# iOS distribution certificate, sign by another developer

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate

My company just built an app for a client who already has an Apple Developer account and had already created their Distribution Certificates.  When the cert is downloaded to our build machine, it obviously isn't signed by us.

Is it possible for us to sign the cert they have already created so we can get the app submitted?

Answer (score 23):

Please ask client to provide you Certificate.p12 that will include the certificate and the private key.

In order to create .p12, go to Keychain Access, select the certificates option in second block in left pane, and then select the certificate you want and right click > Export > Enter the password for p12 > enter Mac password > save at your desired location.

To install at your side, just get that p12 from client, double click to open it, and enter the password which client has entered for p12.

Finally, you are done with getting distribution certificate which is signed at clients place.

Comment: "In order to create .p12 goto keychain access select the certificates option in second block in left pane"....
Is that on the Apple Developer website, or in Mac OS X?

Comment: @Daniel it's Mac OS X Keychain Access app

Answer (score 0):

So I've addressed this one of two ways with my clients. Assumption here is that the client trusts you enough...

1. Ask for the client's Apple Developer login and password info, revoke the current distribution certificate and build a new one using your build machine. Boom! Sign and submit.
2. Ask the client to supply you with the private key he/she used to sign the original distribution certificate. This is done via Keychain Access (see Ronak's answer for specifics).

If said client gets leery about #1, he/she can change their development account password once the app gets submitted and approved, then revoke/make a new distribution certificate.

Getting your client's private key (#2) poses some security risks for your client, but it's the only other way I'm aware of.

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what the security risks are when exporting a Distribution Certificate for installation in some other machine?

Comment: The risk is that if someone with malicious intent gets the private key, he or she could resign apps for distribution that contain malicious code. If that private key signs multiple apps or is tied to an Enterprise distribution cert, you might run into some real issues down the road.

Answer (score -2):

you need to create one in your portal and generate one for your distribution to app store.

Comment: This isn't true. The application can be signed with another developer's certificate.

Comment: Sorry I meant provisioning profile. Yes he can use the same certificate. Just log in to ios provision portal and download it. However, for each app send to app, you have to have a separate provisioning profile.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question. They're making an app for somebody else and would like to know how to sign it with the clients' entitlements. It seems they don't have access to the provisioning portal anyway